# How to get records through a many-to-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these models in my Rails 4 app:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :allocations
  has_many  :payments, :through => :allocations

end
```

---

```
class Allocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :payment

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :allocations
  has_many    :invoices, :through => :allocations

end
```

How can I get all the `invoices` that are related to one particular `payment` X?

I've been trying to get my head around this all day but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Payment.find(X).invoices` provided Payment.find(X) is not nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as:

```
payment.invoices
```

This will follow your association, passing through the allocation model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Identify the Payment and then its invoices like this

```
payment_invoices = Payment.find(payment_id).invoices
```